# Use hmac based client data validation instead of sessions?

Tags: php, session

The principle of sessions is to save data on server side that can be accessed only by the user that has the corresponding session id.

There are two kinds of data: private or public in relationship with the client. Session  it's private for public access of course.

We usually store an user id and some random data(i don't have any concrete example).

I am thinking about not using sessions at all. Instead using a function that checks for the validity of the data sent by user. The server would have a private key that will use for hashing user data.

For example if an user has an id = 9999 we usually store it in a file associated with the session id. Every time the client is making a request we check its session id and retrieve data from the session file associated with it.

I am thinking of storing session data on client side, and every time the client makes a request it sends the hash of this data and the data.

If the user logs in it sends its credentials and the server returns its id a timestamp and a hash calculated based on the user id and the private key.
For any future request the server uses the same function and if the resulting hash is the same then the session is valid and data is previously verified.

Is this a valid way of replacing sessions?
What drawbacks there are beside not being to save server-private session data?

I was concerned by speed and I made a small test...

```
<?php

$session = array(
    'userId' => 999,
    'timestamp' => time()
);
$privateKey = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709';

$startTime = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha1', json_encode($session), $privateKey);
}

echo 'Script took ' . (microtime(true) - $startTime) . ' seconds';
```

...that prints

```
Script took 5.246542930603 seconds
```

I ran this on a laptop(Intel Duo).
In my opinion this is an affordable time(0.000005247 per hash).
Is the test correct?

EDIT: a timestamp is hashed along with the user id in order to ensure session expiration. So that on server side even if the session is valid but it is too old it can be considered as expired.

So to if we are hashing the data along with a timestamp using a private key is it usable in production?

Comment: You might find it interesting to look into ViewState vs. Sessions.  They will make more sense if you are familiar with .Net, but the principles involved are essentially the same as the ones you are exploring here.

Comment: Ticketing systems are a typical way to avoid putting a lot of data into sessions, but still maintain security. I almost always implement a ticketing system for websites, and just put the ticket into a session variable, cookie or URL parameter.

Comment: Like Phoenix said, you are looking for a ViewState technology. I've implemented one before and the trick is simply to create a serializable object that you urlencode afterwards so that your users can't "read" the data easily and create a hash from the urlencoded data so that you can validate the ViewState is still valid before using it...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use .NET for various reasons including the fact that at some point the app could migrate to node.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of a few drawbacks...

1. All the cookie data gets transferred on each HTTP request, making the request slower.
2. The user can see all the data.
3. You still have to check the validity of the hash, so I do not know how much time
   or space this saves you.
4. If it is possible to reverse-engineer the hash (that is, you aren't using some sort of private-key encryption), the user can send anything, and you will say it is valid.
5. If you have a hash that is not able to be reverse-engineered, it is likely somewhat slow to generate.  You do say you are using a private key, so this is likely to apply.  The solution may not scale well.
6. Whoever has to maintain this code after you will wonder what you did.

Comment: @AalexGabi: Unfortunately, all the points are valid. You are exposing session data to the user (he can easily read it), you are also sending this data through the Internet (if connection is not secure, you are basically telling people about user's private data). You will not be even able to distinguish legitimate access from malicious one. Plus, your solution will be non-standard, so chances are it will sometime fail because of design flaws and will be replaced by something else anyway.

Comment: 1. it's a valid point. It depends on the amount of data we need to store in session. 2. specified in question. 3. I added the test for testing the speed. It saves us from Memcache and other session storage for multiple web servers. 4. I think that if we use a private key it is very difficult to reverse engineer. 5. I am thinking about using hmac_sha1 that is in my opinion fast. 6. if it's documented I don't believe it is a problem. Anyway this mechanism is not very complex.

Comment: @Tadeck I don't see what is the difference between having a cookie that contains the session id or an user id! If someone has the session id and basically HTTP headers he can easily authenticate himself as the user(and know his user id). So I think that from the security point of view it's the same except that the user id is visible directly in HTTP headers and/or get params depending what method of storing this data is used.

Comment: @AalexGabi Yes, session hijacking can be a concern.  Sessions time out, though (though that in itself is not sufficient to thwart the session hijacking attack -- you'd want SSL or something along those lines).  Then, the session ID changes.  So, at a minimum you would want a timestamp to be part of the hashed data so that you could emulate this effect, else anyone who can see the hashed data can log in regardless of whether they have the user's full credentials.

Comment: @Andrew I totally agree on adding a timestamp along with the user id. I agree on the fact that anyone who can see the hashed data can log in regardless of whether they have the user's full credentials, but that happens only when a timestamp is not hashed along with users id. I will mention that in the question.

Comment: @AalexGabi: I know you do not see the difference, thus I am trying to explain it to you. No, you can secure yourself from session hijacking (eg. by saving IP of the client without his knowledge), if you know how to do it, and if you store data on the server instead of on the client, you are able to hide some of the methods you use for securing your service. If you store data on the client, you are giving a whole area of possibilities to break into your application. There is also well-known rule called "_Never trust data from the client_". You will learn it sooner or later :)

Comment: @Tadeck Good point IP adress cannot be falsified easily. What about adding it to the data?

Comment: @AalexGabi: If you will make it visible to the user, then I still think it is a bad idea. If you encode it so the data is not visible to the user unless he knows an algorithm & has your private key, then it **may** work (it still gives some possibilities, as the data is not stored on the server and can be modified by client, but since user does not even know that the cookie contains all the data server needs and he does not know what exactly it contains, it is much more secure, but its security still depends on the algorithm).

Comment: @AalexGabi: If you really need to store this data on the client, at least make it as much unreadable & hard to modify as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only good thing about this is you don't have to remember a sessiond_id. It's too much work. I didn't know it's called ViewState but in the end I used a compression to store all those data in a hidden field client-side. Maybe a good practise to use a compression instead of an encryption? It's security by obscurity.

Comment: In its most basic conception, ViewState is an ASP.NET way to take an array of any object that can be serialized to and deserialized from a string, encode (not encrypt, though there is an option for that) the array, and stick the result in a hidden form field.  It has pretty much all the benefits and drawbacks being discussed with this question.

Comment: The idea of not using sessions is because remembering a session id actually hard when you have more than one web server. You have to use Memcached. NFS etc, for sharing those sessions between servers because a load balancer would randomly(almost) choose one web server from its list that would probably not have your session.

Comment: @AalexGabi I haven't looked into it myself, but is there a database server option here (like ASP.NET allows using SQL Server to store session state)?  I'm not saying it's viable or intrinsically better than what you are proposing, but it's another option.  Yet another option would be some sort of backend "session server" (again, something you can just "do" in ASP.NET) that would act as a backend web service to get the session data.  If you're not storing _too_ much in session state, this could be another option if you are wanting to keep the data away from the client side.

Comment: @AalexGabi: In that case I can recommend it. However I'm not using asp.net and and encryption. I've serialized the cache and compressed it with a huffman code. I've downloaded the result to use it as a breakpoint in my application whenever I wanted.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for proposing this option. Unfortunately we don't plan moving to ASP.NET. We would rather use node.js as a server. My question is linked to the way of doing it itself rather than the actual framework user to accomplish that.

Comment: @AalexGabi I didn't mean that you should change technologies.  I was actually referring to how you might accomplish something similar using your framework and/or language of choice, the common theme being that _behind_ your web servers is some central, non-publically-accessible server that handles state information.  This approach has both benefits and drawbacks as well, of course, and it's possible that the approach you propose will work better for you.

Comment: @David I am not sure about security by obscurity. I think if one developer knows the technique he could easily hack something.

Comment: @AalexGabi: Sure, but I stored not only id but many data hence a compression is useful.

Comment: @David Any idea of what compression is adapted for this kind of small data?

Comment: @AalexGabi: Any compression is good it's just an idea I used in my application and I don't think it's the weirdest. But I wouldn't write it again because it's doesn't really pay my bills.